# Getting Specific Values from string

Tags: c#

If i have a string that is

```
string Text="@Time:08:30PM,@Date:08/30/2015,@Duration:4,"
```

How would one go about extracting each of those starting with "@" and ending with the ",". I've searched and I've seen people get one pair with substring, but not how I need it. I want to say:

```
string Time = "08:30PM" //However i can extract it from that string
string Date = "08/30/2015" //etc...
```

Could it be done with Regex?

Thanks!

Comment: How would **you** go? Any code you have tried so far?

Comment: I dont know, hence the question?

Comment: how about reading what and how to ask question on SO?

Comment: you could use regex, but I'd say you could do it just as well using the framework

Comment: @Jonesopolis Actually I think a regular expression would be the best option since there's specific keywords to search for.

Comment: Text.Split('@') (use single quotation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Regex and converting your key-value pairs to a dictionary

```
string input = "@Time:08:30PM,@Date:08/30/2015,@Duration:4,";
var dict = Regex.Matches(input, @"@(\w+):(.+?),")
           .Cast<Match>()
           .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => m.Groups[2].Value);

Console.WriteLine(dict["Time"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) to make an array, then use a substring on each element of the array.

Example:

```
string example = "@Time:08:30PM,@Date:08/30/2015,@Duration:4,";
string[] splitText = example.Split('@');
```

After this, `splitText` will contain these elements:

`{"", "Time:08:30PM,", "Date:08/30/2015,", "Duration:4," }`

Comment: Split on what?  How would you parse the string to fine the Date and Time values?

Comment: Assuming that the string is going to be in consistant format (i.e., data will always be in in the same order), splitting the string is a perfectly valid way of doing this. All you have to do now is to get rid of the comma at the end of each element, then parse its value according to its position.

Comment: Which isn't hard (again, assuming the format is the same every time). Just call a `Replace(",","")` on top of the `Split('@')` and split again based on `:`, parsing the first for key and second for value. Agreed, not the best. But it would certainly work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first shot at it.  Works fine for your example, of course there's edge cases you will probably need to handle as needed.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var text = "@Time:08:30PM,@Date:08/30/2015,@Duration:4,";

     var Time = GetValueForItem("Time", text);
     var Date = GetValueForItem("Date", text);
     var Duration = GetValueForItem("Duration", text);
 }      

 static string GetValueForItem(string item, string text)
 {
     item = $"@{item}:"; //if pre C#6 use string.Format("@{0}:", item)
     var index = text.IndexOf(item);

     var chars = text.Substring(index + item.Length).TakeWhile(c => c != ',');
     return string.Concat(chars);
 }
```

get the index of the text you want, use that to grab all the characters until you reach your delimeter.  Gives you a little more mobility over Regex IMHO.